# Do I need a virus program in a virtual environment?

Tags: windows-7, mac, virtual-machine, anti-virus, parallels

I have a Mac OSX running Parallels desktop with Windows 7. Do I need an anti-virus program? And what free program would be the best if I do? It is also shared on the network.

Comment: You do need an anti-virus

Comment: **Possible duplicate** of [Is my host machine completely isolated from a virus-infected virtual machine?](http://superuser.com/questions/289054/is-my-host-machine-completely-isolated-from-a-virus-infected-virtual-machine), and related to [Tuning Windows 7 for use in a VM](http://superuser.com/questions/251599/tuning-windows-7-for-use-in-a-vm).

Comment: TL,DR:  Yes, you need an AV program.  There are many questions already on Super User concerning the "best" & free AV programs for Windows.

Comment: His question is different from your first link. Your mind-bending search-for-duplicate algorithm failed. :) Muhahaha!

Comment: Might I ask what the difference between them is, @Radoo?

Comment: If you read carefully you can see that guy wanted to protect the SO where the VM relies, where this guy wants to protect the VM from viruses, I don't think he cares about viruses on OSX.

Comment: I guess I wasn't explicit enough. I was talking about protecting the VM not the OSX. I do have anti-virus on the OSX but didn't think it checks the VM. Thanks Radoo for your answer. My problem with MSE is that it has failed the AV test twice in a row now and has lost it's certification from AV-test Certifications.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You mean an anti-virus program... :) Yes, it's best you have one, just in case some little virus tries to sneak in from an USB or from a downloaded file.

You can use [Microsoft Security Essentials](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/security-essentials-all-versions). It's free. I use this on all the PCs I have, or I helped configured. It's not the best there is, but I haven't had any issues with viruses until now, and it's not popping out annoying windows like some other free anti-viruses I know.

Also, make sure you have the Windows Firewall enabled. And User Account Control (UAC).

There are some other tools which can help you on the web side, like anti-spyware software. The one that I like best, perhaps because it's passive, is [SpywareBlaster](http://www.brightfort.com/spywareblaster.html).

========

Later Edit:

If you think MSE is too little of an antivirus, and as you seemed to check the AV-test site, than I would recommend anything that's not free as in pop-ups appear each hour bugging you to upgrade to a deluxe version. You could try [BitDefender Antivirus Free](http://www.bitdefender.com/solutions/free.html).

Comment: Only problem with MSE is that apparently in official tests it fails miserably http://www.tomshardware.com/news/Microsoft-Security-Essentials-AV-TEST-Malware-Certification-Bitdefender,19452.html